# Sails.js global CORS config not working, per-route is

Tags: ajax, node.js, cors, sails.js

I've a SailsJS application, and I'm trying to filter some origins. My system IS working but I have a question.

I tried to allow access to all routes from the cors.js file, with these keys:

```
allRoutes: true,
origin: 'http://my.domain.com'
```

But that doesn't work, all the requests are being rejected with a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

But, if I configure the cors options on a per-route basis, it works. For example, I have this on a route (config/routes.js):

```
'get /myroute': {
    controller: 'MyController',
    action: 'get',
    cors:{
        origin:'http://my.domain.com'
    }
}
```

That works perfectly, so... why the global config/cors.js configuration is not working? I'll really want to put that global and not per-route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/cors

This is the config that works for me. Make sure to specify the methods.

```
module.exports.cors = {
   allRoutes: true,
   origin: '*',
   credentials: true,
   methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',
   headers: 'content-type',
};
```

First try `origin: '*'` but it should also work with `origin: 'yourdomain.com'`. You cannot do really much more than specifying this config.

Comment: I don't know what was, but is working now. I think I haven't activated the headers that you have, maybe that was it. Anyway, you are right and is working now. Thanks! :)